# Create new file transfer configuration using IBM MQMFT

Tags: ibm-mq, file-transfer, websphere-mq-fte

I am using IBM MQMFT hosted on-premise and I have a request to transfer a new file from one server to the other.
Both servers already have MQ agents and are already sending some files across.
I would like to be able to add this new file configuration so that the file can also be picked up.

Please advise the steps required to achieve this. Do I just edit the agent's XML?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wish to send a file from one agent to another, and those agents are already configured...

Use the fteCreateTransfer command for a 'one off':
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/start_new_transfer_cmd.htm

Consider a resource monitor (via fteCreateMonitor) or scheduled transfer (via fteCreateTransfer) if you're doing it on a regular basis:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/create_monitor_cmd.htm

Comment: Thanks Tim. I had the monitor created already. What was missing was the rule configuration in the agent's xml file. I added that and I was good to go